# How to stream my video files from the cloud?

Tags: macos, video, streaming, dropbox, network

I use Dropbox to backup all my important files, but **I'm running out of storage space on my computer**.

Many of the files are video files that take up the majority of my storage, and it's not imperative that they're stored on my computer.

Is there a way to configure Dropbox so some selected files (in my case the videos) are stored in the cloud so I can stream the videos when I need to watch them, but otherwise they don't take up space on my local drive?

Or is there an alternative cloud service that provides this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. Base on my current experiences using Jolicloud OS (http://jolicloud.com), which features a fully operational linux based personalized distribution/operating system and web apps such as Google Chrome/Chromium-Browser web application, and full access to your virtual desktop via web browser, it is possible yes.

Have a look at this: [Access your Dropbox from the JoliCloud Desktop](http://www.jolicloud.com/blog/2011/03/23/access-your-dropbox-from-the-jolicloud-desktop/)

Basically, what Jolicloud does is to link your current Dropbox account into your JoliOS service/system, after which you can gain access to your file's list (and only the list itself) and choose which of these files you wish to download/preview, etc.

From the **[site](http://www.jolicloud.com/blog/2011/03/23/access-your-dropbox-from-the-jolicloud-desktop/)**:

> Some media files like music, photos and videos can be accessed
>   directly inside Jolicloud. This feature depends on the HTML5 audio and
>   video codecs installed in your browser. If you are using Joli OS, make
>   sure to install the HTML5 Video add-on to preview media files.

Illustrations from the JoliOS Blog:

[image]

[image]

[image]

This way you won't spend your disk space in storing locally your Dropbox Files/Folders but you can choose when to use them. The next screenshot is from my desktop, which is JoliOS 1.2 Installed on a 8GB SD Card running in a HP Pavilion dm4 WITHOUT Hard Disk Drive, and where you can see that my Dropbox Capacity is 11.8GB (much more than my SD Card) and in the next screenshot you will see my current SD Card available storage which is yet 2.3 GB and running like a charm.

[image]

[image]

The same behavior is applied to Google Drive.

I can't say for sure how are the JoliOS achieving this features but this wide opens the possibilities for creating new services for the Dropbox Cloud Storage.

The richest feature on the JoliCloud Service is that you can gain access to your Joli's account from technically everywhere. Only Internet and an updated web browser is required.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. There were a lot of good answers, but this one most completely answered my question.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Jungle Disk](https://www.jungledisk.com/personal/desktop/features/). It's a pay service, but it gets you what you want - a locally mountable cloud drive. It can store data locally as well, like Dropbox, but you can configure it as an archive, with no local storage used. It uses [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) or Rackspace as the backend storage, so you pay a $3/month fee, plus an amount per GB per month.

I believe there are similar services out there, and you can just use S3 directly and get something like Panic's [Transmit](http://www.panic.com/transmit/) to mount the S3 storage as a local volume.

Comment: So there's no way to do that with Dropbox?

Comment: Dropbox has a selective sync function, but I'm pretty sure if you enable that, the folders you choose not to sync aren't accessible from your computer, only via the web interface, and it wouldn't allow you to upload anything. Dropbox's philosophy is that you have a folder with you everywhere, including when you're offline, so this idea isn't really what it's built for.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Bitcasa](http://www.bitcasa.com), which is currently in beta and free. It will be 10$/month when the beta ends. It gives you unlimited storage. All music and video files you store on the cloud are streamed to you rather than downloaded. You can delete a folder from your HD once it is synced to Bitcasa. It will remain there until you delete it from the app.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe give [mediafire](http://www.mediafire.com/) a go, it gives you everything you want and you don't have to pay for it, you get 50GB storage for free instead of the 2GB dropbox gives you. (Just a note, I'm not affiliated with these guys in any way, just think 50 gigs free storage is awesome.)

Answer (score 0):

Just gave [BitCasa](http://www.bitcasa.com/) a go and it's my new favourite, this actually works alot like dropbox but allows you to stream online, and storage is virtually unlimited. Check out [this video.](http://www.bitcasa.com/videos/#storageVideo!)